# How to enter an array of non-adjacent cells as first argument in trend function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, trend

I want to find the value for A3.

```
__|_A___
1 | 5
2 | 10
3 | blank
4 | 20
```

So in A3 I add this:

```
=trend( {A1,A2,A4}  ,  {1,2,4}  ,  {3}  )
```

That produces an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `INDEX`:

```
=TREND(INDEX(A:A,{1,2,4}),{1,2,4},{3})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use CHOOSE if you want to use actual cell references:

```
=TREND(CHOOSE({1,2,3},A1,A2,A4),{1,2,4},{3})
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, `CHOOSE` is better here.

Comment: Not necessarily.  I like that the arrays are the same.  If the OP is using the same column then INDEX, I feel, is easier because the arrays match.

Comment: That is a good point, I had overlooked that.

Answer (score 2):

Using `INDEX` with the `[area_num]`

Formula in cell `A3`, where `[area_num]` is optional !

```
=TREND(INDEX((A1,A2,A4),,,{1,2,3}),{1,2,4},{3})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This adds nothing to the previous answers, but if it was needed to have a generalized approach, this could work:

```
=LET( rng, A1:A4,
      targets, {3;5},
       fltr, NOT(ISBLANK( rng ) ),
       TREND( FILTER( rng, fltr ), FILTER( ROW( rng ), fltr ), targets ) )
```

where **rng** is the *y knowns* and **targets** are the expected outputs.

In any case, an interesting question with interesting answers - all of them.